# Сортировка в форме C#

Tags: c#, пузырьковая-сортировка

Помогите решить вопрос.
При нажатии на кнопку генерации получается массив и выводится на экран, с этим проблем нет.
Но как при нажатии на "сортировка" вывести отсортированный массив в другой textBox?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] array = new int[20];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rand.Next(-20, 100);
            textBox1.Text += " " + array[i];
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox1.Text;
        textBox2.Text = a;

    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    
}
```

}

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте массив полем

```cs
private int[] array = new int[20];

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(-20, 100);
    }
    textBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", array);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Array.Sort(array); // вместо этого, здесь вы можете вызвать метод своей сортировки
    textBox2.Text = string.Join(" ", array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала получаем текст и записываем его в переменную `str`, после этого разделяем полученный текст на основе символа пробела при помощи метода `Split()`.

Полученный результат (`string[]`) перебираю методом `Select` из пространства имен `System.Linq` (необходимо будет подключить сверху `using System.Linq`).

Параметром является какая-то функция, в моем случае функция, которая конвертит каждый элемент массива в `int`. Затем применяем метод `OrderBy`, который на основе какого-то ключа сортирует элементы.

И в конце приводим к массиву с помощью метода `ToArray()`

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = textBox1.Text;
    
    //отсортированные элементы
    int[] arr = str.Split(' ').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

    textBox2.Text = string.Join(" ", arr);
}
```

Comment: `Split(' ')` = `Split()` :)

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, а есть еще подобное?

Comment: ага `str.Split().Select(int.Parse).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();`

Comment: @aepot Невероятно, даже и представить такое не мог